# How can I split a string into two separate arrays using the .NET framework?

Tags: .net, arrays, string

I've got a string containing both ints and a string. How do I split it into two arrays, one for ints and one for the string? I also need to maintain the order because I'm writing a file parsing system that depends on reading in and correctly splitting these strings.

EDIT: Here's a sample input, and what I would like as output:

`~Wolf 100 45 4 5`

Wolf as a string in an array
and the ints in their own separate array.

EDIT: A little more info:

I'm getting five variables from the user and writing them to a file. Then, I'm reading them back in again. I need to be able to identify the numbers by the name. Now that I think about it, actually, I'm not sure splitting the string is the best way to go. Is there a way to put both ints and strings in a single array? That way I can find the name, and know that the next four ints after it belong to it.

Comment: Providing sample input and output for us to work with would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue)` with a `String` as the key, and an `Integer()` array as the value.  This will give you the lookup functionality you are looking for...

```
Sub Main()
    Dim Input As String = "~Wolf 100 45 4 5" & Environment.NewLine & _
                          "~Racoon 500 41 9 7"

    Dim Dict As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer())

    For Each Line As String In Input.Split(Environment.NewLine)
        Dim Key As String
        Dim Values As Integer() = New Integer() {}

        For Each LineValue As String In Line.Split(" "c)
            Dim TryInt As Integer

            If Integer.TryParse(LineValue, TryInt) Then
                ReDim Preserve Values(Values.Length)
                Values(Values.Length - 1) = TryInt
            Else
                Key = LineValue.Trim("~")
            End If
        Next

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(Key) Then
            Dict.Add(Key, Values)
        End If
    Next

    ' How to use                             \\'
    Dim WolfVals As Integer() = Dict.Item("Wolf")

    For Each Int as Integer in WolfVals
        Console.WriteLine(Int)
    Next

    Console.Read()
End Sub
```

Comment: Interesting. I haven't used dictionaries before. Could you explain a little what is going on?

Comment: @Elliot It is fairly self explanatory.  See the input?   It reads it line by line, splits each line by a space, builds the integer array, stores the key, then populates the dictionary

Comment: Sorry, I was fixing your syntax highlighting. A little hack. Rollback if you wish.

Comment: @Anthony Ahh, I see.  No prob.  Wish SO would fix this nonsense.

Comment: @Josh, That makes a little more sense. What's the `dim` in front of `input` and `dict`?

Answer (score 2):

> I need to be able to identify the
>   numbers by the name.

I'll not repeat the string.split answers, but perhaps you shouldn't use arrays in both cases but could use an object to represent the user? e.g.

```
public class User
{
  public string UserName{get;set;}
  public List<int> Parameters= new List<int>();
}
```

You could then put the user into an array,list, dictionary etc to look up the user and then retrieve the parameters that the user has input.

Comment: The other advantage of this approach is that you could create the class from their input. If you make the class serializable (e.g. [XmlSerializable]) then you could let the framework do the reading/writing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Pseudologic

- First split the string into an array
- Create a `List<int>` and `List<string>`
- Iterate thru the array and use Int.TryParse and if the return is true, insert into the `List<int>`, otherwise `List<string>`

--- Edited with example -----

```
var list = line.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var intList = new List<int>();
var textList = new List<string>();
int val = 0;
foreach(var item in list)
{
   if(Int.TryParse(item, out val))
    intList.Add(val);
   else
    textList.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Fadrian says:

```
List<int> integers = new List<int>();
List<string> strings= new List<string>();

foreach(var variable in originalstring.split(" ")){
 try{
  integers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(vaiable));
 }
 catch(){
  strings.Add(variable)
 }
}
```

But from what I can read I would do something else. I would create an XML or database table or somethin.

IF it really has to be in plain text file, use a different delimiter for your name, and numbers: eg

name | number1 ,number2,number...

then split once on "|" and first one is name, second one numbers. Then split the second one on ","

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how the data is stored in that string. If there's a separator between the numbers, use `String.Split()`

Comment: I can easily put a seperator between the numbers, but how do I get two arrays out of String.Split? As far as I know, it outputs one array.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to have 2 different separators, example:

Wolf#100,45,4,5

Then you could perform:

```
string[] splitTheFirst = String.Split('#');
string[] splitTheSecond = splitTheFirst[0].Split(',');
int[] splitTheThird = splitTheFirst[1].Split(',');
```

Then you would have an array of strings with the strings from the first split, and an array of ints from the second array from the first split.

Comment: Sorry, you'd have to have them all as string[], as that's what String.Split returns, and then you'd have to do Convert.ToInt32 on each string in splitTheThird - d'oh!

Comment: Reading the extra information you've added to your quesion, this won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
string input = "~Wolf 100 45 4 5";
IEnumerable<string> words = input.Split(' ')
                            .Where(a => a != null && a.Trim() != string.Empty);

List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
List<string> strings = new List<string>();
int value;

foreach (string word in words)
{
    if (int.TryParse(word, out value))
    {
        numbers.Add(value);
    }
    else
    {
        strings.Add(word);
    }
}
```